# Вывод данных в шаблоне на Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

PHP-код

```
$newscity = mysql_query("SELECT `newscity`.*, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `newscity_comments` WHERE `newscity_comments`.`id_news`=`newscity`.`id`) AS `comment_count` FROM `newscity` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10"); 
while  ($rows_news = mysql_fetch_assoc($newscity)){
  $row_news['time'] = times($rows_news['time']);
  $arraynewscity[] = $rows_news;
}
$smarty->assign('newscity',$arraynewscity);
```

В шаблоне

```
{foreach from=$newscity item=itemnewscity}
<li>
<img src="{$home}/files/newscity/{$itemnewscity.kartinka}">
<h3>{$itemnewscity.name}</h3>
<p>{$itemnewscity.anons|nl2br}...</p>
<p><img src="{$home}/style/{$skin}/images/clock.png" width="16" height="15" style="margin-right:4px;"><span class="left" style="margin-right:8px;">
{$itemnewscity.time}
</span><img src="{$home}/style/{$skin}/images/saycloud.png" width="14" height="16" style="margin-right:4px;"><a href="{$home}/pages/newscity.php?id={$itemnewscity.id}">{$itemnewscity.comment_count}</a></p>
</li>
{/foreach}
```

Время не обрабатывается моей функцией times, а выводится в обычном unix-формате. Как поправить?

Comment: Smarty_Variable Object (3)
 ->value = Array (3)
  0 => Array (9)
    id => "3"
    id_user => "1"
    name => "Мэр Киева Черновецкий подал в отставку"
    text => "<p>Леонид Черновецкий написал заявлен..."
    kartinka => "402943_news_4.jpg"
    time => "1349182744"
    prosmotrov => "137"
    anons => "<p>Леонид Черновецкий написал заявлен..."
    comment_count => "3"



Также выводится в unix-формате. Такое чувство что проблема тут {$itemnewscity.time}

Answer (score 3):

О я понял в чем проблема.
Тут у тебя косяк указано не $rowS_news а $row_news

```
while  ($rows_news = mysql_fetch_assoc($newscity)){
  $row_news['time'] = times($rows_news['time']);
  $arraynewscity[] = $rows_news;
}
```

Лучше не использовать окончание s сам с этим путаюсь.

Comment: Плюсую за внимательность!

Comment: О спасибо) Сам ненавижу когда такие ошибки получаются)

Answer (score 1):

```
function times ($timestamp) {
   return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Если я написал что не обрабатывается моей функцией то это значит что данная функция у меня есть.

function times($timestamp) 
{
global $realtime;
$datestamp = date('d.m.o в H:i', $timestamp);
$today = date("d.m.o",$realtime); 
$yestoday = date("d.m.o", $realtime-24*3600);
$datestamp = str_replace($today,"Сегодня",$datestamp); 
$datestamp = str_replace($yestoday,"Вчера",$datestamp); 
return $datestamp;
}

Comment: Тогда по идее ошибок в коде нет. Проверьте, что содержит массив $arraynewscity.

Comment: Скриншот - http://upwap.ru/d/2919684/62934311ad4296c69e97d00050b6f968/Скрин.png И время там выводится в unix-формате.

Comment: Значит функция не обрабатывает правильно значение. Попробуйте вместо функции просто написать:  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $rows_news['time']);

Comment: Не помогло. Тоже самое.

Comment: Проверяйте свою функцию, не работает.

Comment: Дело не в ней.

Comment: Не может быть такого, что не помогло. Переименуй ключ time ($row_news['time']) в какой-нибудь другой и посмотри, что будет в массиве.

Comment: Ты выведи массив не $newscity а $arraynewscity то что до поступления в смарти. может смарти переменную .time по своему обрабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю в Smarty есть встроенная функция которая может преобразовать время timestamp в удобный для пользователя формат. В Вашем случае будет так:

```
{$itemnewscity.time|date_format:"Y-m-d"}
```

Comment: А если у меня будет не время, а что-то другое то как я должен использовать свои функции?

Comment: Читайте мануал - http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.modifier.date.format.tpl. в date_format данные "могут быть переданы Smarty в виде временных меток unix, временных меток mysql или в виде любой строки, содержащей день, месяц и год, которую может обработать функция strtotime()."